# Haskell length function error message

Tags: haskell

As sort of "Wat" for Haskell, it's pointed out at the end of [haskell for teaching](http://profsjt.blogspot.co.il/2017/10/is-haskell-right-language-for-teaching.html) that

```
length (1,2)

1
```

vs.

```
length (1,2,3)


<loads of error messages>
```

The questions is why? And how to correct this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'correct' it?

Comment: Not correct the compiler, but the source code. For example `(1,2,3)::(Int, Int, Int)`. Of course, not knowing why the error message, it's not a valid "correction" at all.

Comment: Why do you think the source code needs to be corrected?

Comment: `length` isn't really useful for tuples, because the type already tells you how many elements are present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `length` is:

```
Foldable t => t a -> Int
```

which you could read as returning the number of `a`s within some collection of `a`s. There is a [`Foldable` instance for pairs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#line-311):

```
instance Foldable ((,) a) where
    foldMap f (_, y) = f y

    foldr f z (_, y) = f y z
```

which acts on the second element of the pair, which you can see with `toList`:

```
toList (1,2)
> [2]
```

Since there is no `Foldable` instance for larger tuples, you receive an error when trying to evaluate `length (1,2,3)`.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind this is that tuples with 2 elements implement the `Foldable` typeclass, but higher order tuples don't implement it.